# Measure Scala Code coverage in testcases in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, testing, code-coverage

I am in a situation, where I have a number of ScalaTest written tests (JUnit compatible), and I want to measure how good codecoverage I get, when running the test.

I don't want to use SBT directly, but have an Eclipse Scala project, in which I have a number of test cases that I want to run.

What would be the best way for me to go?

Comment: Which build tool do you use, if not sbt. Maven? Do you want to test scala code or did you only write your tests in scala?

Comment: I'm using the normal eclipse "scala builder" etc. and when I'm done I'm exporting the projects as eclipse plugin. I want to test scala code, and the tests is also written in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) for code coverage in Eclipse.  Install it using the update site.

Note that it's won't show up in the Scala perspective, only the Java perspective, but that's ok because you can still run your Scala-based unit tests that way.

When you install it, it adds a new "run" button to your toolbar.  When you use this is runs the unit tests you choose, generates a coverage report, and highlights your code to show what has and has not been covered.

I just tested it with a Scala project with Scala unit tests, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it works, but you need to annotate the class to run with a junit runner

Answer (score 0):

Check SCCT https://github.com/mtkopone/scct 
http://mtkopone.github.com/scct/

Unfortunately, doesn't have Eclipse plugins (yet)

Comment: no code pushes since 2012 (Support for scala 2.10.0-RC3), 39 open tickets, and 3 pull requests that have been pending since 2013!

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in scala for "plain scalatest classes"

all it requires is to add an annotation to your scalatest class to make it run as a Junit (see annotation below). This uses scalatests own junitrunner.

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FeatureSpec with Matchers with GivenWhenThen with StrictLogging {

once you've done that, you will see that you can now run this class in eclipse as a "scala junit test". You will also be able to "coverage as -> junit test" as well.

If you have the eclemma plugin installed, then you will see the coverage panel (you may have to manually add this to your scala perspective) with the coverage provided by your test and you will also get the red/green/yellow line by line coverage in your classes.

life is good!

Comment: just to disclose some more details, I'm using the junit 4.12, scalatest 2.2.5, eclipse mars

Comment: more info on the scalatest junitrunner: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_junit_runner